# QList of pixmaps or Qlist of pointers to pixmaps confusion

Tags: qt

I have to merge some pixmaps and I want to add them first in a qlist and then merge them .While I know the procedure how to merge them I am confused about which one to use  QList of pixmaps or Qlist of pointers to pixmaps and what is the difference and if it's possible to do the merging with a qlist of pointer of pixmaps .

```
 GraphicsPixmapItem *pix =static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(item1);
 QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix2 =static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(item2);


 ////////////////Merge Pixmaps/////////////////////

 int pix_height=75;
 int pix_width=50;
 //use QList of pixmaps
 QList <QPixmap> dragImages;
 dragImages<<pix->pixmap()<<pix2->pixmap();//it works
 QSize dragPixSize(pix_width*dragImages.size()+50,pix_height);
 QPixmap dragpix(dragPixSize);
 dragpix.fill(Qt::transparent);
 QPainter painter;
 painter.begin(&dragpix);

 for(int i=0; i < dragImages.size(); ++i){
 painter.drawPixmap(pix_width*i,0,pix_width,pix_height,dragImages.at(i));
 }
 painter.end();
 //////////////////////////////////////////
 //or use Qlist of pointers to pixmaps?
 QList <QPixmap*> pix; //how do I add pix->pixmap() here?
```

Comment: QPixmap is copy-on-write type, so you should usually handle them as values (or references if needed). Same applies to all Qt containers. If you have pointer to CoW-type, you should be suspicuous about why.

Comment: `QList<QPixmap>` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `QPixmap` is a cheap-to-copy value, thus you don't need to use pointers: you can use the values directly. If you don't know why you need to use `QList`: don't use it. It's deprecated in this case - use `QVector`.

First, let's extract the pixmaps from a vector of graphics items:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <algorithm>

using QPixmapVector = QVector<QPixmap>;

QPixmapVector getPixmaps(const QVector<QGraphicsItem*> &items) {
  QPixmapVector ret;
  for (auto item : items) {
    auto *pixItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem*>(item);
    if (pixItem)
      ret.push_back(pixItem->pixmap());
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Then, we can merge the pixmaps given in a vector, leaving some extra size at the right end of the strip:

```
QPixmap mergePixmaps(const QPixmapVector &pixmaps, const QSize &extraSize) {
  auto size = extraSize;
  for (auto &pix : pixmaps) {
    size.setWidth(size.width() + pix.width());
    size.setHeight(std::max(size.height(), pix.height()));
  }
  QPixmap ret(size);
  ret.fill(Qt::transparent);
  QPainter p(&ret);
  int x = 0;
  for (auto &pix : pixmaps) {
    p.drawPixmap(x, 0, pix.width(), pix.height(), pix);
    x += pix.width();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The particular variant of the merge operation you wanted is, then:

```
QPixmap myMerge(QGraphicsItem *item1, QGraphicsItem *item2) {
  auto pixmaps = getPixmaps({item1, item2});
  return mergePixmaps(pixmaps, {50, 75});
}
```